# How to build a custom primary key for a table in Access?

Tags: ms-access

I'm importing data from a csv file into a table that looks like the following:

```
+------------+------------------------+----------------+
|   date_1   |      tournament_1      |     misc_1     |
+------------+------------------------+----------------+
| 01/01/2020 | ATP-ACAPULCO           | random_data_1  |
| 01/01/2020 | ATP-ACAPULCO           | random_data_2  |
| 02/01/2020 | ATP-ACAPULCO           | random_data_3  |
| 01/01/2020 | CALGARY-CHALLENGER-MEN | random_data_4  |
| 02/01/2020 | CALGARY-CHALLENGER-MEN | random_data_5  |
| 02/01/2020 | CALGARY-CHALLENGER-MEN | random_data_6  |
| 03/01/2020 | CALGARY-CHALLENGER-MEN | random_data_7  |
| 03/01/2020 | CALGARY-CHALLENGER-MEN | random_data_8  |
| 01/01/2021 | ATP-ACAPULCO           | random_data_9  |
| 01/01/2021 | ATP-ACAPULCO           | random_data_10 |
| 02/01/2021 | ATP-ACAPULCO           | random_data_11 |
| 02/01/2021 | CALGARY-CHALLENGER-MEN | random_data_12 |
| 03/01/2021 | CALGARY-CHALLENGER-MEN | random_data_13 |
+------------+------------------------+----------------+
```

I need to be able to link this table to another **linked** table which has a list of tournaments from another system:

```
+------+----------------------+
| id_2 |     tournament_2     |
+------+----------------------+
|  123 | Mexico-Acapulco-2020 |
|  456 | Canada-Calgary-2020  |
|  789 | Mexico-Acapulco-2021 |
| 1011 | Canada-Calgary-2021  |
+------+----------------------+
```

As the second table is linked then my plan was to build a third 'cross-reference' table:

```
+------+----------------------+------------------------+
| id_2 |     tournament_2     |      tournament_1      |
+------+----------------------+------------------------+
|  123 | Mexico-Acapulco-2020 | ATP-ACAPULCO           |
|  456 | Canada-Calgary-2020  | CALGARY-CHALLENGER-MEN |
|  789 | Mexico-Acapulco-2021 | ATP-ACAPULCO           |
| 1011 | Canada-Calgary-2021  | CALGARY-CHALLENGER-MEN |
+------+----------------------+------------------------+
```

However, I need unique pairs of tournaments and I don't.

To get around this I could build a primary key for the first table as follows:

```
+------------+------------------------+----------------+-----------------------------+
|   date_1   |      tournament_1      |     misc_1     |      tournament+year_1      |
+------------+------------------------+----------------+-----------------------------+
| 01/01/2020 | ATP-ACAPULCO           | random_data_1  | ATP-ACAPULCO-2020           |
| 01/01/2020 | ATP-ACAPULCO           | random_data_2  | ATP-ACAPULCO-2020           |
| 02/01/2020 | ATP-ACAPULCO           | random_data_3  | ATP-ACAPULCO-2020           |
| 01/01/2020 | CALGARY-CHALLENGER-MEN | random_data_4  | CALGARY-CHALLENGER-MEN-2020 |
| 02/01/2020 | CALGARY-CHALLENGER-MEN | random_data_5  | CALGARY-CHALLENGER-MEN-2020 |
| 02/01/2020 | CALGARY-CHALLENGER-MEN | random_data_6  | CALGARY-CHALLENGER-MEN-2020 |
| 03/01/2020 | CALGARY-CHALLENGER-MEN | random_data_7  | CALGARY-CHALLENGER-MEN-2020 |
| 03/01/2020 | CALGARY-CHALLENGER-MEN | random_data_8  | CALGARY-CHALLENGER-MEN-2020 |
| 01/01/2021 | ATP-ACAPULCO           | random_data_9  | ATP-ACAPULCO-2021           |
| 01/01/2021 | ATP-ACAPULCO           | random_data_10 | ATP-ACAPULCO-2021           |
| 02/01/2021 | ATP-ACAPULCO           | random_data_11 | ATP-ACAPULCO-2021           |
| 02/01/2021 | CALGARY-CHALLENGER-MEN | random_data_12 | CALGARY-CHALLENGER-MEN-2021 |
| 03/01/2021 | CALGARY-CHALLENGER-MEN | random_data_13 | CALGARY-CHALLENGER-MEN-2021 |
+------------+------------------------+----------------+-----------------------------+
```

I could then create the one to one pairing as follows:

```
+------+----------------------+-----------------------------+
| id_2 |     tournament_2     |    tournament_1 + year_1    |
+------+----------------------+-----------------------------+
|  123 | Mexico-Acapulco-2020 | ATP-ACAPULCO-2020           |
|  456 | Canada-Calgary-2020  | CALGARY-CHALLENGER-MEN-2020 |
|  789 | Mexico-Acapulco-2021 | ATP-ACAPULCO-2021           |
| 1011 | Canada-Calgary-2021  | CALGARY-CHALLENGER-MEN-2021 |
+------+----------------------+-----------------------------+
```

However, I can't create the key via a calculated field as I can't link on that so I'd have to fall back on some VBA to create it on import.

Am I missing a more simple or elegant solution here?

Comment: You could use an event-driven [Data Macro](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Create-a-data-macro-b1b94bca-4f17-47ad-a66d-f296ef834200) like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/egPET.png) to automatically create your composite key value when you add records. That will work whether you insert the rows by importing them or by adding them manually.

Comment: Awesome, thanks. Learnt a new thing in Data Macros too. Lots simpler than coming back to VBA after a year!! Happy to accept the above as an answer...